# How to extract security identifier from member attribute of a group?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, security-identifier

Suppose we have an AD Group with some members as foreign security principals. The format of the values in the member attribute in that case is as follows:

CN=S-1-5-21-XXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXX-XXXX,CN=ForeignSecurityPrincipals,DC=dmc,DC=001,DC=net

We have a translate command to trace the member using SID (S-1-5-21-XXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXX-XXXX);

```
([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier] $SID).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).value
```

Is there a way in powershell to extract out the SID from the member attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regular expressions.  Something like this should work:

```
$targetString = 'CN=S-1-5-21-2440625168-151597401-477403795-1001,CN=ForeignSecurityPrincipals,DC=dmc,DC=001,DC=net'

$regEx = '(?<SID>S-\d-\d+-(\d+-){1,14}\d+)'

if($targetString -match $regEx) {
    ([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier] $Matches.SID).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest will be to use the SubString function:

```bsh
$CN = 'CN=S-1-5-21-2440625168-151597401-477403795-1001,CN=ForeignSecurityPrincipals,DC=dmc,DC=001,DC=net'

$SID = $CN.SubString(3, 45)

([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier] $SID).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).value
```